# Unable to get cookie authentication working with pouchdb

Tags: node.js, nosql, pouchdb

I'm having trouble getting pouchdb working on the client side. I've looked through several other Stack Overflow posts, but I still haven't been able to figure it out. I've also looked into pouchdb-authentication, but it doesn't seem to be the one I'm looking for.

Below is my Express backend.

I first get the password from the user and validate it before making a post request to /_sessions to get the token. I then return a string back to the client. The string looks like this:

> AuthSession=dGVzdDo1RTRDMDlFNDoCqn-ogpyksRGBXe7x7DVinw075A; Version=1;
>   Expires=Tue, 18-Feb-2020 16:09:32 GMT; Max-Age=600; Path=/; HttpOnly

In the POST route for localhost:8080/session

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, users[0].password, function (error, result) {
 if (error) { res.status(400).json({ error }); }
  if (result === true) {
    // return a cookie auth token from couchdb
    axios.post('http://localhost:5984/_session', {
      name: req.body.username,
      password: users[0].password
    }).then((response) => {
      const cToken = response.headers['set-cookie'][0];
      return res.json(cToken); // send auth token back to client
    }).catch((err) => {
      return res.status(400).json(err);
    });
  });
};
```

However, the client side doesn't seem to recognize that I got a cookie token and I get this error:

> { error: "unauthorized", reason: "You are not authorized to access this
>   db.", name: "unauthorized", status: 401, message: "You are not
>   authorized to access this db." }

Here is my client side code:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/session/', { username: this.form.username, password: this.form.password }).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data);
  const db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/somedb', { headers: { Cookie: res.data } });
  db.info().then((info) => {
    db.put({
      _id: 'mydoc',
      title: 'test'
    }).then((response) => {
      // handle response
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Is it because I'm not getting the header/the cookie isn't being set? Can I not just pass the string when I create the pouchdb instance?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The intermediary code is getting the `AuthSession` cookie but where/how is the `Set-Cookie` header presented in the response?  Posting the actual HTTP response headers the client receives would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I was able to figure it out. All I had to do was change ```  { headers: { Cookie: res.data } } ``` to ```{ajax:  { headers: { Cookie: res.data } } } ```